# PostgreSQL to get top 2 group multiple rows into single columns based on total number

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate, greenplum

for example i have this table

```
ek_id   phone_number    product     ctgry          usage
12345   525556456       DSX         Ads              4
78910   525556789       stillery    Communications   2
12345   525556456       Dtscou      eCommerce        3
78915   525556777       Dyandra     Education        2
12345   525556456       DynAd       Ads              1
78910   525556789       eCreat      Communications   4
78915   525556777       tivemeasure eCommerce        5
78910   525556789       klanku      Ads              6
78910   525556789       Ema         Communications   7
```

and i want to make like this

```
ek_id   phone_number    product         ctgry                 usage
12345   525556456       DSX | stillery  Ads | Education         8|6
78910   525556789       DSX | eCreat    Ads | eCommerce        10|8 
78915   525556777       ema | klanku    Ads | Communications    9|5
```

so basically grouping top 2 products and ctgry on pipe separated columns based on highest total of usage.

regards

Answer (score 0):

To group, will be something as

```
   SELECT ek_id, phone_number, 
      array_agg(product) as product, 
      array_agg(ctgry) as ctgry, 
      array_agg(usage) as usage
   FROM t
   GROPUP BY 1,2
```

... but need to understand if `phone_number` is also to group.

> get top 2 group multiple rows into single columns based on total number

"Top" is about `order by DESC`, and "multiple rows" is about `HAVING count(*)>1` ... so

```sql
   SELECT ek_id, -- seems the PK
      max(phone_number), -- ? please define better
      string_agg(array_agg(product),' | ') as product, 
      string_agg(array_agg(ctgry),' | ') as ctgry, 
      string_agg(array_agg(usage),'|') as usage
   FROM t
   GROPUP BY 1
   HAVING count(*)>1
   ORDER BY sum(usage) DESC
   LIMIT 2
```

> grouping top 2 products and ctgry on pipe separated columns based on highest total of usage

The `LIMIT 2` is to filter only the "top 2", `sum(usage)` checks the "highest total of usage". For layout with pipes you can include `string_agg(x,' | ')`  as in `string_agg(array_agg(product),' | ')`.

Comment: Hi Peter thanks for the response. i think i need to edit the question. what i mean with the TOP 2 is only for the products and the ctgry. so for example i have 5 products . so only the top 2 products that shows on the columns instead of 5 (the top 2 based on the highest sum of total usage ). i try your code, it worked but limiting the overall result.